# How to reconstruct text entities with Hugging Face's transformers pipelines without IOB tags?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, transformer-model, named-entity-recognition, huggingface-transformers

I've been looking to use Hugging Face's Pipelines for NER (named entity recognition). However, it is returning the entity labels in inside-outside-beginning (IOB) format but [without the IOB labels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging)). So I'm not able to map the output of the pipeline back to my original text. Moreover, the outputs are masked in BERT tokenization format (the default model is BERT-large).

For example:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
nlp_bert_lg = pipeline('ner')
print(nlp_bert_lg('Hugging Face is a French company based in New York.'))
```

The output is:

```
[{'word': 'Hu', 'score': 0.9968873858451843, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
{'word': '##gging', 'score': 0.9329522848129272, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
{'word': 'Face', 'score': 0.9781811237335205, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
{'word': 'French', 'score': 0.9981815814971924, 'entity': 'I-MISC'},
{'word': 'New', 'score': 0.9987512826919556, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': 'York', 'score': 0.9976728558540344, 'entity': 'I-LOC'}]
```

As you can see, New York is broken up into two tags.

How can I map Hugging Face's NER Pipeline back to my original text?

Transformers version: 2.7

Comment: Can you please provide a full [mcve], including how you loaded your `nlp_bert_lg` model?

Comment: Added @dennlinger

Answer (score 24, accepted):

EDIT 12/2023:
As pointed out, the `grouped_entities` parameter has been deprecated. The correct way is to use the `aggregation_strategy` parameters as pointed in the [source code](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.10.1/_modules/transformers/pipelines/token_classification.html) .
For instance:

```
text = 'Hugging Face is a French company based in New York.'
tagger = pipeline(task='ner', aggregation_strategy='simple')
named_ents = tagger(text)
pd.DataFrame(named_ents)
```

Gives the following output

```
[
   {
      "entity_group":"ORG",
      "score":0.96934015,
      "word":"Hugging Face",
      "start":0,
      "end":12
   },
   {
      "entity_group":"MISC",
      "score":0.9981816,
      "word":"French",
      "start":18,
      "end":24
   },
   {
      "entity_group":"LOC",
      "score":0.9982121,
      "word":"New York",
      "start":42,
      "end":50
   }
]
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
The 17th of May, a new pull request https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/3957 with what you are asking for has been merged, therefore now our life is way easier, you can you it in the pipeline like

```
ner = pipeline('ner', grouped_entities=True)
```

and your output will be as expected. At the moment you have to install from the master branch since there is no new release yet. You can do it via

```
pip install git+git://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git@48c3a70b4eaedab1dd9ad49990cfaa4d6cb8f6a0
```

Comment: Thanks, that was super helpful. Note that the argument is now named `aggregation_strategy`

Comment: WARNING: `aggregation_strategy='max'` or `aggregation_strategy='average'` relies on softmax probabilities --> these scores are **not** proper confidence scores! See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309642/why-is-softmax-output-not-a-good-uncertainty-measure-for-deep-learning-models

Comment: token_classifier = pipeline("ner", model=model,aggregation_strategy='simple', tokenizer=tokenizer,grouped_entities=True)

`{'entity_group': 'B_name', 'score': 0.96226656, 'word': 'Pratik', 'start': 1141, 'end': 1149}
{'entity_group': 'I_name', 'score': 0.9272271, 'word': 'kr', 'start': 1150, 'end': 1157}
{'entity_group': 'L_name', 'score': 0.7290683, 'word': 'kumar', 'start': 1158, 'end': 1163}`
Ideally, it should be grouped to just name ? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking at this in 2022:

- the `grouped_entities` keyword is now deprecated
- you should use `aggregation_strategy`: default is `None`, you're looking for `simple` or `first` or `average` or `max` -> see [documentation of the `AggregationStrategy` class](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.10.1/_modules/transformers/pipelines/token_classification.html)

```py
from transformers import pipeline
import pandas as pd

text = 'Hugging Face is a French company based in New York.'

tagger = pipeline(task='ner', aggregation_strategy='simple')
named_ents = tagger(text)
pd.DataFrame(named_ents)
```

```json
[{'entity_group': 'ORG',
  'score': 0.96934015,
  'word': 'Hugging Face',
  'start': 0,
  'end': 12},
 {'entity_group': 'MISC',
  'score': 0.9981816,
  'word': 'French',
  'start': 18,
  'end': 24},
 {'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.9982121,
  'word': 'New York',
  'start': 42,
  'end': 50}]
```

Comment: WARNING: `aggregation_strategy='max'` or `aggregation_strategy='average'` relies on softmax probabilities --> these scores are **not** proper confidence scores! See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309642/why-is-softmax-output-not-a-good-uncertainty-measure-for-deep-learning-models

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, as of now (version 2.6, and I think even with 2.7), you cannot do that with the `pipeline` feature alone. Since the `__call__` function invoked by the pipeline is just returning a list, see [the code here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L764). This means you'd have to do a second tokenization step with an "external" tokenizer, which defies the purpose of the pipelines altogether.

But, instead, you can make use of the [second example posted on the documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/usage.html#named-entity-recognition), just below the sample similar to yours. For the sake of future completeness, here is the code:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoTokenizer
import torch

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dbmdz/bert-large-cased-finetuned-conll03-english")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

label_list = [
    "O",       # Outside of a named entity
    "B-MISC",  # Beginning of a miscellaneous entity right after another miscellaneous entity
    "I-MISC",  # Miscellaneous entity
    "B-PER",   # Beginning of a person's name right after another person's name
    "I-PER",   # Person's name
    "B-ORG",   # Beginning of an organisation right after another organisation
    "I-ORG",   # Organisation
    "B-LOC",   # Beginning of a location right after another location
    "I-LOC"    # Location
]

sequence = "Hugging Face Inc. is a company based in New York City. Its headquarters are in DUMBO, therefore very" \
           "close to the Manhattan Bridge."

# Bit of a hack to get the tokens with the special tokens
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(tokenizer.decode(tokenizer.encode(sequence)))
inputs = tokenizer.encode(sequence, return_tensors="pt")

outputs = model(inputs)[0]
predictions = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=2)

print([(token, label_list[prediction]) for token, prediction in zip(tokens, predictions[0].tolist())])
```

This is returning exactly what you are looking for. Note that the ConLL annotation scheme lists the following in its [original paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W03-0419.pdf):

> Each line contains four fields: the word, its part-of-speech tag, its chunk tag and its named entity tag. Words tagged with O are outside of named entities and the I-XXX tag is used for words inside a named entity of type XXX. Whenever two entities of type XXX are immediately next to each other, the first word of the second entity will be tagged B-XXX in order to show that it starts another entity. The data contains entities of four types: persons (PER),organizations (ORG), locations (LOC) and miscellaneous names (MISC). This tagging scheme is the IOB scheme originally put forward by Ramshaw and Marcus (1995).

Meaning, if you are unhappy with the (still split) entities, you can concatenate all the subsequent `I-` tagged entities, or `B-` followed by `I-` tags. It is not possible in this scheme that two different (immediately neighboring) entities are both tagged with only the `I-` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know when it splits the words by ## ?

Comment: Words are split based on the notion of "subword units", see for example [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/byte-pair-encoding-the-dark-horse-of-modern-nlp-eb36c7df4f10). Essentially, it forces a smaller vocabulary, while still being able to reproduce rare words by combining different subwords, which are indicated by the `##`. I.e., there might be subwords `byte`, `-`, and `pair`, but not `byte-pair`, so it would instead be represented by three "combined" tokens `byte`, `##-`, `##pair`. The full vocab is defined by the model itself, see the `vocab.txt` file.