# Transformer Pipeline for NER returns partial words with ##s

Tags: python, pytorch, named-entity-recognition, huggingface-transformers

How should I interpret the partial words with '##'s in them returned by the Transformer NER pipelines? Other tools like Flair and SpaCy return the word and their tag. I have worked with the CONLL dataset before and never noticed anything like this. Moreover, why are words being divided like this?

Example from the HuggingFace:

```
from transformers import pipeline

nlp = pipeline("ner")

sequence = "Hugging Face Inc. is a company based in New York City. Its headquarters are in DUMBO, therefore very" \
           "close to the Manhattan Bridge which is visible from the window."

print(nlp(sequence))
```

Output:

```
[
    {'word': 'Hu', 'score': 0.9995632767677307, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
    {'word': '##gging', 'score': 0.9915938973426819, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
    {'word': 'Face', 'score': 0.9982671737670898, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
    {'word': 'Inc', 'score': 0.9994403719902039, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
    {'word': 'New', 'score': 0.9994346499443054, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
    {'word': 'York', 'score': 0.9993270635604858, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
    {'word': 'City', 'score': 0.9993864893913269, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
    {'word': 'D', 'score': 0.9825621843338013, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
    {'word': '##UM', 'score': 0.936983048915863, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
    {'word': '##BO', 'score': 0.8987102508544922, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
    {'word': 'Manhattan', 'score': 0.9758241176605225, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
    {'word': 'Bridge', 'score': 0.990249514579773, 'entity': 'I-LOC'}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pytorch transformers and BERT make 2 tokens, the regular words as tokens and words + sub-words as tokens; which divide words by their base meaning + their complement, addin "##" at the start.

Let's say you have the phrease: `I like hugging animals`

The first set of tokens would be:

```
["I", "like", "hugging", "animals"]
```

And the second list with the sub-words would be:

```
["I", "like", "hug", "##gging", "animal", "##s"]
```

You can learn more here:
https://www.kaggle.com/funtowiczmo/hugging-face-tutorials-training-tokenizer

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks! I'll accept your answer as is, but if you know, how would you go about extracting the complete original token with a single tag for each?  It seems that we need a decoder on the tokenizer, but how to reassemble the sub-tokens into complete tokens?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937617/how-to-reconstruct-text-entities-with-hugging-faces-transformers-pipelines-with) related question. Unfortunately, you cannot use pipelines for this (as of version 2.8), without writing your own custom code to merge tokens back together, since the return values from the pipeline are very restrictive.

Comment: As @dennlinger said, you'd have to do it manually. You could after generating the pipeline adding the dict values to a list, looping it while enumerating and add a condition the `if i.startswith('##'): then i-1 = i-1+i` then `replacing '##' with ''`. If you want to dwelve deep into working with transformers tokens, check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaQ0CBlQ4cY&feature=emb_logo

Answer (score 1):

Use the `aggregation_strategy` to group the entities:

```
pipeline('ner', model="YOUR_MODEL", aggregation_strategy="average")
```

Read more about strategies [here](https://%20https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TokenClassificationPipeline.aggregate_words).