# Named Entity Recognition with Huggingface transformers, mapping back to complete entities

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm looking at the documentation for [Huggingface pipeline for Named Entity Recognition](https://huggingface.co/transformers/task_summary.html#named-entity-recognition), and it's not clear to me how these results are meant to be used in an actual entity recognition model.

For instance, given the example in documentation:

```
>>> from transformers import pipeline

>>> nlp = pipeline("ner")

>>> sequence = "Hugging Face Inc. is a company based in New York City. Its headquarters are in DUMBO, therefore very"
...            "close to the Manhattan Bridge which is visible from the window."

This outputs a list of all words that have been identified as an entity from the 9 classes     defined above. Here is the expected results:

print(nlp(sequence))

[
{'word': 'Hu', 'score': 0.9995632767677307, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
{'word': '##gging', 'score': 0.9915938973426819, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
{'word': 'Face', 'score': 0.9982671737670898, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
{'word': 'Inc', 'score': 0.9994403719902039, 'entity': 'I-ORG'},
{'word': 'New', 'score': 0.9994346499443054, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': 'York', 'score': 0.9993270635604858, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': 'City', 'score': 0.9993864893913269, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': 'D', 'score': 0.9825621843338013, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': '##UM', 'score': 0.936983048915863, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': '##BO', 'score': 0.8987102508544922, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': 'Manhattan', 'score': 0.9758241176605225, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': 'Bridge', 'score': 0.990249514579773, 'entity': 'I-LOC'}
]
```

While this alone is impressive, it isn't clear to me the correct way to get  "DUMBO" from:

```
{'word': 'D', 'score': 0.9825621843338013, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': '##UM', 'score': 0.936983048915863, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
{'word': '##BO', 'score': 0.8987102508544922, 'entity': 'I-LOC'},
```

---or even to the cleaner multiple token matches, like distinguishing "New York City" from simply the city of "York."

While I can imagine heuristic methods, what's the correct intended way to join these tokens back into correct labels given your inputs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reconstruct text entities with Hugging Face's transformers pipelines without IOB tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937617/how-to-reconstruct-text-entities-with-hugging-faces-transformers-pipelines-with)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The pipeline object can do that for you when you set the parameter:

- **transformers < 4.7.0**: [grouped_entities](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.6.0/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.TokenClassificationPipeline) to `True`.
- **transformers >= 4.7.0**: [aggregation_strategy](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TokenClassificationPipeline.aggregation_strategy) to `simple`

```py
from transformers import pipeline

#transformers < 4.7.0
#ner = pipeline("ner", grouped_entities=True)

ner = pipeline("ner", aggregation_strategy='simple')

sequence = "Hugging Face Inc. is a company based in New York City. Its headquarters are in DUMBO, therefore very close to the Manhattan Bridge which is visible from the window."

output = ner(sequence)

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'entity_group': 'I-ORG', 'score': 0.9970663785934448, 'word': 'Hugging Face Inc'}
, {'entity_group': 'I-LOC', 'score': 0.9993778467178345, 'word': 'New York City'}
, {'entity_group': 'I-LOC', 'score': 0.9571147759755453, 'word': 'DUMBO'}
, {'entity_group': 'I-LOC', 'score': 0.9838141202926636, 'word': 'Manhattan Bridge'}
, {'entity_group': 'I-LOC', 'score': 0.9838141202926636, 'word': 'Manhattan Bridge'}]
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that `grouped_entities` parameter comes with version __3.0.2__. So, if you get an error, you solve the problem with updating the __transformers__ library!

Comment: How to speed up `ner = pipeline("ner", grouped_entities=True)`? It's pretty slow.

Comment: @red-devil This line is loading the model. In case it is not in your cache it will always take some time to load it from the huggingface servers. When deployment and execution are two different processes in your scenario, you can preload it to speed up the execution process. Please open a separate question with some information regarding the amount of the data you are processing and the exact code you are executing.

Comment: The [reference](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#tokenclassificationpipeline) for NER using pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

Quick update: `grouped_entities` has been deprecated.

> UserWarning: `grouped_entities` is deprecated and will be removed in
> version v5.0.0, defaulted to
> `aggregation_strategy="AggregationStrategy.SIMPLE"` instead.
> f'`grouped_entities` is deprecated and will be removed in version
> v5.0.0, defaulted to `aggregation_strategy="{aggregation_strategy}"`
> instead.'

you will have to change your code to:

```
ner = pipeline("ner", aggregation_stategy="simple")
```