# Company name extraction with bert-base-ner: easy way to know which words relate to which?

Tags: bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, tagging, pos-tagger

Hi I'm trying to extract the full company name from a string description about the company with bert-base-ner. I am also open to trying other methods but I couldn't really find one. The issue is that although it tags the orgs correctly, it tags it by word/token so I can't easily extract the full company name without having to concat and build it myself.

Is there an easier way or model to do this?

Here is my code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification
from transformers import pipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("dslim/bert-base-NER")

nlp = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

ner_results = nlp(text1)
print(ner_results)
```

Here is my output for one text string:

```
[{'entity': 'B-ORG', 'score': 0.99965024, 'index': 1, 'word': 'Orion', 'start': 0, 'end': 5}, {'entity': 'I-ORG', 'score': 0.99945647, 'index': 2, 'word': 'Metal', 'start': 6, 'end': 11}, {'entity': 'I-ORG', 'score': 0.99943095, 'index': 3, 'word': '##s', 'start': 11, 'end': 12}, {'entity': 'I-ORG', 'score': 0.99939036, 'index': 4, 'word': 'Limited', 'start': 13, 'end': 20}, {'entity': 'B-LOC', 'score': 0.9997398, 'index': 14, 'word': 'Australia', 'start': 78, 'end': 87}]
```

Comment: Usually it's your responsibility to build the final string. So called post-processing

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue and solved it by using a better model called "xlm-roberta-large-finetuned-conll03-English" which is much better than the one you're using right now and will render the complete organization's name rather than the broken pieces. Feel free to test out the below-mentioned code which will extract the full organization's list from the document. Accept my answer by clicking on tick button if it founds useful.

```
from transformers import pipeline
from subprocess import list2cmdline
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
import docx2txt
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
import time
start = time.time()
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
model_checkpoint = "xlm-roberta-large-finetuned-conll03-english"
token_classifier = pipeline(
    "token-classification", model=model_checkpoint, aggregation_strategy="simple"
)



def text_extraction(file):
    """"
    To extract texts from both pdf and word
    """
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        return extract_text(file)
    else:
        resume_text = docx2txt.process(file)
    if resume_text:
        return resume_text.replace('\t', ' ')
    return None



# Organisation names extraction
def org_name(file):
    # Extract the complete text in the resume
    extracted_text = text_extraction(file)
    classifier = token_classifier(extracted_text)
    # Get the list of dictionary with key value pair "entity":'ORG'
    values = [item for item in classifier if item["entity_group"] == "ORG"]
    # Get the list of dictionary with key value pair "entity":'ORG'
    res = [sub['word'] for sub in values]
    final1 = list(set(res))  # Remove duplicates
    final = list(filter(None, final1)) # Remove empty strings
    print(final)

       
org_name("your file name")

end = time.time()

print("The time of execution of above program is :", round((end - start), 2))
```

Comment: What does `matcher` do in this context?

Comment: Sorry Peter that was a minor mistake. It was supposed to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can keep your original code and model, and try this setting instead: aggregation_strategy="simple":

In your code, add it as an extra parameter:
`nlp = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, aggregation_strategy="simple")`

It was suggested in this in the post below:
[How to reconstruct text entities with Hugging Face's transformers pipelines without IOB tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937617/how-to-reconstruct-text-entities-with-hugging-faces-transformers-pipelines-with)